# Add column that counts times value occurs in results

Tags: sql

I have a query with 5 columns. I want to add 1 column that defines the number of times the value in column 2 (ItemCode) occurs in the results.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 

Items.Description_0 AS [Items.Description], 
Items.ItemCode,
warehouse_location, 
Stock.Quantity AS StockQty,
Stock.warehouse

FROM 
((SELECT gbkmut.artcode, gbkmut.warehouse, ISNULL(gbkmut.warehouse_location,'') AS warehouse_location, 
SUM(gbkmut.aantal) AS Quantity FROM gbkmut

INNER JOIN Items ON Items.ItemCode = gbkmut.artcode 

INNER JOIN voorrd ON voorrd.artcode=gbkmut.artcode 
AND voorrd.magcode=gbkmut.warehouse 

INNER JOIN ItemUnits ON ItemUnits.Unit = Items.PackageDescription 
WHERE gbkmut.reknr = Items.GLAccountDistribution 
AND (( gbkmut.transtype IN ('N', 'C', 'P', 'X')  
AND gbkmut.datum BETWEEN {d '2000-01-09'} AND {d '2031-02-08'} )  )    
AND  (gbkmut.warehouse='MAG1' )   

AND Items.Type IN ('S','B')  
AND NOT (Items.GLAccountAsset IS NOT NULL AND     Items.IsSerialNumberItem=1)  AND NOT (Items.Type = 'S' AND    ItemUnits.UnitType = 'T') 

GROUP BY gbkmut.artcode, gbkmut.warehouse,   ISNULL(gbkmut.warehouse_location,'')

HAVING SUM(gbkmut.aantal) > 0)) Stock

INNER JOIN Items ON Items.ItemCode=Stock.artcode
WHERE Items.ItemCode like '10.27021%'

ORDER BY Items.ItemCode
```

Comment: The easy way out answer is to use a cte.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy version, use a common table expression (cte):

```
with cte as
(
[your huge select]
)
select t1.*, t2.codecount 
from cte t1
join (select ItemCode, count(*) as codecount from cte group by ItemCode) as t2
    ON t2.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode
```